# using django authentication and session on remote front end

Tags: django, authentication

I have a website that front-end and back-end are on different servers. Front-end part is on angular 2 and webpack and gets dynamic data from back-end using ajax.
Back-end uses django framework for database management and ORM.
Is it possible to use django authentication and session management and Auth.User model for the front-end in back-end part?

Comment: Simple I will say YES

Comment: @itzmeontv How should I do that?